# startVPNTunnel() doesn't work on iOS 14 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, vpn

Since iOS 14 released startVPNTunnel() stopped working and the app doesn't create VPN connection.

My configuration is the following:

```
 private func _save(_ account: VPNServer, completion: VPNConfigureCompletion?) {
        let keychain = Keychain(service: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
        keychain["sharedSecret"] = account.key
        let ikev2Protocol = NEVPNProtocolIKEv2()
        ikev2Protocol.useExtendedAuthentication = false
        ikev2Protocol.authenticationMethod = .sharedSecret
        ikev2Protocol.disconnectOnSleep = false
        ikev2Protocol.serverAddress = account.ip
        ikev2Protocol.sharedSecretReference = keychain[attributes: "sharedSecret"]?.persistentRef
        ikev2Protocol.remoteIdentifier = account.ip

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            ikev2Protocol.enableFallback = true
        }

        vpnManager.protocolConfiguration = ikev2Protocol
        vpnManager.isEnabled = true
        vpnManager.saveToPreferences { error in
            if let err = error {
                print("Failed to save profile: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                self.delegate?.setConnectionStatus(status: .disconnected)
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.NEVPNStatusDidChange, object: "Failed to save profile")
            } else {
                completion?()
            }
        }
    }
```

This code saves configuration, but when you try to connect, it throws (even manually in iPhone settings). It worked correctly on iOS 13. We have tried to make server to IPv6 compatible, but without success. I also tried different to add VPN.IKEv2.ChildSecurityAssociationParameters without success.
Anyone has solution?